# jQuery slideshow, go to previous image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to make the .next() work in reverse way, so it goes to the previous image in the slideshow instead of the next one, however, when I press the button it goes blank (nothing appears).

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="slide1.png" class="sliderImage" />
    <img src="slide2.png" class="sliderImage" />
    <img src="slide3.png" class="sliderImage" />
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)"><div id="relative"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" id="sliderArrowLeft"></i></div></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><div id="relative"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" id="sliderArrowRight"></i></div></a>
```

Script:

```
$('#slider img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          $('#slider :first-child').hide()
             .next('img').delay(1).fadeIn()
             .end().appendTo('#slider');},
          30000);

          $("#sliderArrowRight").click(function() {
              $('#slider :first-child').hide()
             .next('img').delay(1).fadeIn()
             .end().appendTo('#slider');
          });

          $("#sliderArrowLeft").click(function() {
              $('#slider :first-child').hide()
             .prev('img').delay(1).fadeIn()
             .end().appendTo('#slider');
          });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: better make a fiddle ...

Comment: could you please code your complete code, so its easier to help you!

Comment: alright, updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is prev('img') doesn't exists for the slider first child. So change your function like this :

```
$("#sliderArrowLeft").click(function() {
    $('#slider :first-child').hide();
    $('#slider :last-child').delay(1).fadeIn().prependTo('#slider');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for making it clear for me! This works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this for #sliderarrowleft

```
           $('#slider img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#slider :first-child').hide()
                        .next('img').delay(1).fadeIn()
                        .end().appendTo('#slider');
                },30000);

            $("#sliderArrowRight").click(function () {
                $('#slider :last-child').hide();
                $('#slider :first-child').hide()
                        .next('img').delay(1).fadeIn()
                        .end().appendTo('#slider');
            });

            $("#sliderArrowLeft").click(function () {
                $('#slider :first-child').hide();
                $('#slider :last-child').hide()
                        .prev('img').delay(1).fadeIn()
                        .end().prependTo('#slider');
            });
```

Comment: Almost. On the first click the next (not previous) image would appear below the current one (instead of actually fading in the previous). Works on 3rd click though.

Comment: Appreciate it. This time it goes to the next image (instead of previous) on the first click. On 2nd click, it goes back to the first image shown (slide1.png) but on the 3rd click it shows the previous one (slide3.png)